# Show CS (Column Separator) in a RED input-capable field using DSPATR(&ATTR)

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

I'm displaying a DSPF format from RPG using no indicators, but P-field attributes to vary color and input-capability. Turquoise and Yellow fields have the CS (Column separator) by default. If I use a format with indicators, an input-capable red field with CHGINPDFT(CS) at record-level shows me the dots. 
I don't succeed to get the dots with an attribute, neither with another CHGINPDFT(CS)at field-level.
Is there an option (keyword) in the DSPF that allows me RED and also CS, with P-field attributes?

I add a screen image of my Client-Access session, all defaults
[image]

the field alter "Titolo" is red undelined with CS, impossible?

Comment: What is your 5250 emulation/display setup?  It shouldn't even be possible to get column separators with red, regardless of CHGINPDFT.  At least not on traditional terminals, or faithful emulators of such terminals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 5250 data stream does not support COLOR(RED) together with DSPATR(CS).  I realise you have CHGINPDFT(CS) but it amounts to the same thing.  See http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzakc%2Frzakcmstdfcolor.htm and http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/topic/rzakc/rzakcmstdfdspat.htm

If you are seeing the separators in a red field, it might be settings on the terminal emulation program.

Comment: After seeing the screen image, I am very surprised.  Can you post the DDS that produces this?

Comment: You asked the right question: IT'S NOT RED. The DSPF has  ENTFLDATR((*COLOR RED) (*DSPATR UL))  specified. The emulator temporarily changes the field, leaving the CS intact.